# Can't get Form validation error in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to get the form validation error message and put it in a Django message. When I try entering the wrong data in the form field to try and produce an error, I get nothing in the error message but the form is raising the validation error. If I submit the correct data in the form fields, the success message shows.
Here is my code:

```py
def job_details(request, job_id):
    job_details = job.objects.get(id=job_id)
    job_tags = jobTag.objects.all()

    form = JobApplicationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = JobApplicationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            application = jobApplicant(
                email = form.cleaned_data['email'],
                cv = form.cleaned_data['cv'],
                job = job_details
            )
            application.save()
            messages.success(request, f"Application submitted successfully!")
            print("message sent")
            return redirect ('job_details', job_id)
    else:
        for error in form.errors:
            messages.error(request, error)

        form = JobApplicationForm()

    context = {'job_details': job_details,
                'job_tags': job_tags,
                'form': form}
    return render(request, 'job-details.html', context)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `else` portion of your code seems to be in the wrong place though. That's where you have it in your code or did you make an error while editing your question?

Comment: I'd say, if input field raises a validation error, it means it wont submit the form to backend until its fixed by the user... That could be why you don't get your error message from backend triggered, perhaps?

Comment: True, the `else` was indented wrongly. Thanks @Damoiskii

Comment: @sajeyksmwangi no problem mate. Assuming it's now working. ;-)

Comment: Perfectly mate: